# Connect SATA storage device to 2 computers at a time

Tags: hard-drive, sata

There is an IP camera NVR (a box that has a SATA HDD 3,5" in it and records the cameras video to the HDD).

But I don't have access to the "NVR as root".

**Question**: How can I (while the NVR is using the HDD in RW mode) reach the HDD in a read-only mode? ex.: A rbpi can do it?

Comment: You likely cant. SATA is not designed to take instructions from 2 devices simultaneously.

Comment: ... so NVR is just the recorder connected to a camera. I would expect that the documentation of the device will explain how to do it. After all a video recorder that doesn't allow viewing the recorded footage is a pretty useless device... If you don't find it in the documentation, another user of the same setup might be able to help, but only if you specify what solution exactly you are using. Please don't respond in a comment, update your question with more details and any other new info like what have you already tried to resolve the issue with what results. More details => better answers.